# Calculate reward value based on percentage non-linearly?

Tags: perl, math

I am programming a gambling type game where the rewards need to get bigger as the chance gets less.

For example here are the target max rewards for the following chance percentages:

```
100% = 1
50% = 250
0.01% = 2000
```

What formula can I use to calculate a reward given just the percentage value that would conform with the values above?

**Additional Information 1:**

Here are my values and reward multipliers - where the house edge is 2%.

```
Percent: 97.651 ::: multiplier :: 1.0035 
Percent: 91.28 ::: multiplier :: 1.0736 
Percent: 86.3 ::: multiplier :: 1.1355 
Percent: 78.893 ::: multiplier :: 1.2421 
Percent: 72.1 ::: multiplier :: 1.3592 
Percent: 65.38 ::: multiplier :: 1.4989 
Percent: 50 ::: multiplier :: 1.96 
Percent: 47.76 ::: multiplier :: 2.0519 
Percent: 34.252 ::: multiplier :: 2.8611 
Percent: 29.51 ::: multiplier :: 3.3209 
Percent: 19.45 ::: multiplier :: 5.0385 
Percent: 11.44 ::: multiplier :: 8.5664 
Percent: 8.453 ::: multiplier :: 11.5935 
Percent: 6.876 ::: multiplier :: 14.2524 
Percent: 4.893 ::: multiplier :: 20.0286 
Percent: 2.465 ::: multiplier :: 39.7565 
Percent: 1.45 ::: multiplier :: 67.5862 
Percent: 1 ::: multiplier :: 98 
Percent: 0.46 ::: multiplier :: 213.0434 
Percent: 0.2348 ::: multiplier :: 417.3764 
Percent: 0.0984 ::: multiplier :: 995.9349 
Percent: 0.0344 ::: multiplier :: 2848.8372 
Percent: 0.01 ::: multiplier :: 9800
```

What I simply want to figure out is if there is an algorithm that can determine the maximum possible winning amount based on the 3 values above. The reasoning, is that at 50% I would like the maximum reward to be 250 and at 0.01% I would like it to be 2000 - **regardless** of what the bet amount is. I can easily figure out the maximum bet to conform to those values.

So perhaps the question should have made no mention of gambling. The question simply is can I figure out other values based on a percentage input that would conform with the 3 values above?

Comment: the example reward schedule is not increasing in terms of expected value. if the chances are 100%, then reward 1 is fine. for 50% the reward of 250 is also fine it exceeds the expected value 2. for 0.01% however the expected fair reward value consistent with the previous ones would be 10,000. however the example brings it down to 1/5th of it. in contrast the 250 one is 125x the fair reward value. i. e. the question does not know what it wants and is quite muddleheaded about probability.

Comment: But, the above answer assumes the bet is always constant, no? If the maximum bet at 100% = 1 for a reward of 1 and the maximum bet at 0.01% = 0.2 for a maximum reward of 2000 - then that conforms to the expected values doesn't it?

Comment: let's assume your bet is $1. A 100% chance wins you $1 and it is break even. The breakeven reward for a 50% chance would be $2 since $1 = $2 * 50% = $2 * 0.5. The breakeven reward for a 0.01% chance would be $10,000 since $1 = $10,000 * 0.01% = $10,000 * 0.0001. For the 50% case you specify 250 which is above the breakeven value of 2. But for 0.01% you specify 2000 which is well below the breakeven value of 10,000. (and to completely confound things you add `(or 0%)` for good measure)

Comment: I probably did not ask my question properly or you are not understanding me. Please see above additional info.

Comment: the mention of gambling is not a problem. probability enthusiasts LOVE to talk about gambling even if some of us frown upon actual gambling. i still feel your question does not fit into any probabilistic framework that i am aware of. hopefully somebody else has an insight. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple inverse reward function.

Let's say that P is a value on the range [0,1]. `P=1` means it's a guaranteed win, while `P=0` means it's a guaranteed loss.

A simple algorithm for the reward value, `R`, as a function of the probability of winning, `P`, would be something like:

```
R(P) = (1/P) -1
```

This is valid for all values of `P` except `P=0`, in which case, the reward should be zero, as it's a guaranteed loss, which nobody would take, and if it's a guaranteed win, the payout is zero.

So, an implementation of this in C would be:

```
float reward(float chance) {
  float result;
  if (chance <= 0.0f) {
    result = 0.0f;
  } else {
    result = (1.0f / chance) - 1.0f;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This will give a rapidly changing curve. A permalink can be found here to a sample plot:

http://fooplot.com/plot/jqvf3sqmys

If you want to accelerate the dropoff, just change the exponent for `(1/P)`, ie:

```
R(P) = (1/P)^2 -1  (Faster drop off)
R(P) = (1/P)^3 -1  (MUCH Faster drop off)
```

This is a general way to calculate such rewards. If you want it to fit the three data points you noted above, you will have to resort to curve fitting, spline interpolation, generalized least squares, etc, to get a best-fit of the above equation to your data points. Or you could use Taylor polynomials to generate a simple 4-th order polynomial equation (ie: `ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e`) that fits all your data points **exactly.**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For a logical player to engage in gambling, the expected return value must be greater than his stake. The expected return value is `reward · probability`, so we have the equation

```
reward · probability - stake ≥ 0
```

If a part of the winnings are taxed (tax in percent), then we have

```
reward · (1 - tax) · probability - stake ≥ 0
```

If all other variables are known, we can calculate good rewards as

```
reward  ≥ stake /( (1-tax) · probability )
```

So the reward needed is proportional to the inverse of the probability.

A zero probability of winning isn't good (this is a division by zero error), but this should be considered a “lost” game, so no reward calculation should be neccessary.

If the calculated reward is too high, it can always be capped (but this makes the player unlikely to engage in the gamble)

```
my $tax = 0.02; # 2%
my $max_reward = 2000;
my $min_reward = 1;

sub calculate_reward {
  my ($probability, $stake) = @_;
  die "zero probability, neccessary stake is infinite" if $probability <= 0;
  my $reward = $min_reward + $stake/( (1-$tax) * $probability);
  $reward = $max_reward if $reward > $max_reward;
  return $reward;
}
```

Comment: "For a logical player to engage in gambling ..." - oxymoron?

Comment: @randomstring nope, gambling can pay off (my answer is about asserting that). This is good for PvP gambling, or when no real value can be transferred (e.g. in a game: *NPC: lend me three carrots for a minute, I'll give you 5 back later! Player: ok. \*NPC runs away\**). This answer is not appliccable to slot machines etc., where the casino would be the losing party

Comment: sure. i had the casino slot machine scenario in mind because the question seemed to be designing the reward with a well-known probability, rather than a skill-based game where the probability is not known to the reward-designer.